How do I access and read C:\Users\admins\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History via windows network?
How do I access and read C:\Users\admins\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History via windows network (maybe via powershell). I have domain admin rights on the network i need to access C:\Users\admins\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History folder, read its contents like I can read it locally, export data from it to CSV and save to admin computer. I need get as much as possible information from thi folder via network.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

something like: net use x: \\pcname\c$\Users\...\History and then x: (replace the ... with full path)

You can’t by default only that specific user can access that folder within AppData.  The fact you are a domain administrator doesn’t change the access to a user profile directory

If your computer is joined to the domain which you are domain admin and the domain admins group is a local admin, you can use the admin share as LPChip mentioned \\computerxyz\c$\folder\path\xzy. Once you find the file, you can use PowerShell's Export-Csv command with some googling, this is very trivial, and more likely a question for AI such as ChatGPT than SU IMHO. This is a perfect example question for it where it can tell you, you can try, do more googling or ask more questions, etc. to get a concise answer that should work, no human subjectiveness needed, plain old admin share 101.
